# Error 501 calling web service with WSO2 proxy service

Tags: web-services, proxy, wso2, runtime-error, esb

I am trying to call a web service. 
When I make the call directly working properly. 
But when I publish in WSO2 ESB with the URL Proxy Service Pass Throught returns me the following error.

501 Not Implemented

Response Headers

X-Squid-Error: ERR_UNSUP_REQ 0
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from srv-endian2.5.1-test.datadec.es:8080
Content-Type: text/html 
X-Cache: MISS from srv-endian2.5.1-test.datadec.es
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 09:01:58 GMT 
Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Connection: Close

I used sometimes Proxy Pass Throught with other web services success (ie: eBay) and it works correctly.

Any idea?
Can someone help me with this issue?
Thanks
Rafa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to the backend not being able to handle chunking correctly. You can put the following property in inSequence to disable chunking.

```
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: I had already tried that possibility. 
Just get the answer faster, but gives the same error. 
Here's the code proxy.
.....
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.seurvalencia.es/IC/SERVICE.ASMX"/>
               <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
....

Comment: When send xml message directly to http://www.seurvalencia.es/IC/SERVICE.ASMX works fine.

Comment: You have to set it before hitting the send mediator   <target> <inSequence> <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/> <send> <endpoint> <address uri="seurvalencia.es/IC/SERVICE.ASMX"/>; </endpoint> </send> </inSequence> <outSequence> <send/> </outSequence> </target>

Comment: One way to find this problem would be to analyse the payloads being sent into and sent out of the ESB and find any discrepancies. You can do this either by enabling wire logs on ESB or by intercepting messages by tcpmon. What is the ESB version you are using?

Comment: Finally the property DISABLE_CHUNKING is the solution.
Thanks Amila.